# Pandas downsampling more time intervalls?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I'm doing some resampling on data and I was wondering why resampling 1min data to 5min data creates MORE time intervals than my original dataset?
Also, why does t resample until 2018-12-11 (11 days longer!) than the original datset?

1-min data:

[image: original 1-min data]

result of resampling to 5-min intervalls:

[image]

This is how I do the resampling:

```
df1.loc[:,'qKfz_gesamt'].resample('5min').mean()
```

Comment: How looks your code?

Comment: If check `df1['qKfz_gesamt'].resample('5min').mean()` vs `df1['qKfz_gesamt'].resample('5min').mean().dropna()` get same lengths?

Comment: I think problem is `resample` create consecutive values and if not exist in original are added NaNs, so possible output data has more values.

Comment: Length is smaller but the beginning and ends are still "longer" than the original data...

Comment: `beginning and ends are still "longer"` - is possible explain more?

Comment: 1-min data goe s until 2018-11-30 and resampled 5-min data until 2018-12-11 (+ 11 days!). Where could those days come from !?!

Comment: Maybe data are in another position, what is original data `print (df1['qKfz_gesamt'].index.max())` ?

Comment: Also is possible are swapped some months with days in datetimes? So `12-11-2018` is parsed like december, but it should be november?

Comment: I think the parsing of dates works all right. If I do `print (df1['qKfz_gesamt'].index.max())` it goes until  `2018-12-11`, so I guess I have to manuallay select date range and then do resamling?

Comment: need filter datetime by maximal, like `df1 = df1.loc[:'2018-11-30', :]` ?

Comment: yeah...looks like it! thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering why resampling 1min data to 5min data creates MORE time intervals than my original dataset?

Problem is if no consecutive values in original pandas create consecutive 5minutes intervals and for not exist values are created `NaNs`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'qKfz_gesamt': range(4)}, 
                   index=pd.to_datetime(['2018-11-25 00:00:00','2018-11-25 00:01:00',
                                         '2018-11-25 00:02:00','2018-11-25 00:15:00']))  
print (df1)
                     qKfz_gesamt
2018-11-25 00:00:00            0
2018-11-25 00:01:00            1
2018-11-25 00:02:00            2
2018-11-25 00:15:00            3

print (df1['qKfz_gesamt'].resample('5min').mean())
2018-11-25 00:00:00    1.0
2018-11-25 00:05:00    NaN
2018-11-25 00:10:00    NaN
2018-11-25 00:15:00    3.0
Freq: 5T, Name: qKfz_gesamt, dtype: float64

print (df1['qKfz_gesamt'].resample('5min').mean().dropna())
2018-11-25 00:00:00    1.0
2018-11-25 00:15:00    3.0
Name: qKfz_gesamt, dtype: float64
```

> why does t resample until 2018-12-11 (11 days longer!) than the original datset?

You need filter by maximal value of index:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2018-11-25', periods=10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (df1)
            a
2018-11-25  0
2018-11-26  1
2018-11-27  2
2018-11-28  3
2018-11-29  4
2018-11-30  5
2018-12-01  6
2018-12-02  7
2018-12-03  8
2018-12-04  9

df1 = df1.loc[:'2018-11-30']
print (df1)
            a
2018-11-25  0
2018-11-26  1
2018-11-27  2
2018-11-28  3
2018-11-29  4
2018-11-30  5
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.loc[df1.index <= '2018-11-30']
print (df1)
            a
2018-11-25  0
2018-11-26  1
2018-11-27  2
2018-11-28  3
2018-11-29  4
2018-11-30  5
```